# Why is map<bool,int> m={{1,2},{3,4},{5,0}}; size 1 and not 3?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, uniform-initialization

Quite peculiar:

```
map<bool,int> mb={{1,2},{3,4},{5,0}};
cout << mb.size(); 
map<int,int> mi={{1,2},{3,4},{5,0}};
cout << mi.size();
```

prints out

> 13

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`std::map` is unique-key. `1`, `3`, `5` all yield `true` when converted to `bool`.

Answer (score 7):

Just a guess, but your first map has `bool` as the key type, and all values `1, 3 and 5` evaluate to true.

You only ever rewrite the same entry.

Answer (score 6):

Your first map has bool as the key. There are only two values of bool. You provide ints as the input. Non-0 ints are true and 0 ints are false. All your keys are therefore true. Two of them are overwritten by the last one. This is why the size is 1.